# Updating Fields with values from Python list using ArcPy UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm currently trying to update the fields of a shapefile, with a list I've compiled outside of the arcpy environment. Trying both UpdateCursor which I can't seem to get to work, and FieldCalculator. FieldCalculator just updates it with "P[2]"

```
photoname = []

for p in shp_list:
    name = p[2]
    photoname.append(name)

    # arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_shapefile,"PhotoName","'p[2]'","PYTHON_9.3")
```

I've also tried:

```
updt_cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_shapefile, fields)
for row in updt_cursor:
    val = str(row[0])
    for p in shp_list:
        if val in p:
            row[2] = p_name
            updt_cursor.updateRow(row)
```

And UpdateCursor is blank.

I know I could create a .txt from the list, then update the fields with the line in the .txt file with InsertCursor, but I feel like there should be a more efficient way to do this. For context, I'm creating point shapefiles of the X/Y from the exif data, and want to fill in the corresponding image name.

Comment: Make sure to close the update cursor.  You can do so with `del updt_cusor` at the end, but the better practice is to use a `with` block so it gets done automatically.  See the examples:  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm

Comment: @mikewatt Updated to be consistent with the documentation still no change.

Comment: Then you're left with logical errors.  The `if val in p:` condition is never met-- if it was, you would get an exception because you never defined `p_name`.  Do some standard debugging here: print out `shp_list` to make sure it contains what you expect, print `val` from within the main loop, print `p` from within the inner loop, etc.

Comment: Agreed with @mikewatt in that you need to check your iterables. Can you show us what `shp_list` and some of the corresponding `val` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your field calculator statement change it to:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(out_shapefile,"PhotoName","'" + p[2] + "'","PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: This works, kind of. now it's just an iteration fix. They're all photo 22. I can figure it out from here. I can't believe I missed something so simple.